# How to center a Button (MdTextButton) in MDTopAppBar in KivyMD?

Tags: python, user-interface, kivymd

I'm trying to center a button (MDTextButton) in KivyMD in the MDTopAppBar, but fail on positioning it correctly (center horizontal and vertical). If using action_items everything get misaligned as you can see in the following picture:

[image: Screenshot:]

Is there a way of correctly position a button (MDTextButton) in the MDTopAppBar at all? I'd appreciate any help and hints. Thx!

This is my KV code:

```
KV = '''
<DrawerClickableItem@MDNavigationDrawerItem>
    focus_color: "#e7e4c0"
    text_color: "#b3b198"
    icon_color: "#a86e0a"
    ripple_color: "#c5bdd2"
    selected_color: "#0c6c4d"


<DrawerLabelItem@MDNavigationDrawerItem>
    text_color: "#b3b198"
    icon_color: "#b3b198"
    focus_behavior: False
    selected_color: "#4a4939"
    _no_ripple_effect: True


MDScreen:

    MDTopAppBar:
        id: toolbar
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}

        right_action_items:
            [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]            
        left_action_items:
            [['home', lambda x: setattr(screen_manager, "current", "screen_Home")]]
            
        MDTextButton:
            text: "Test"
            text_color: "white"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 1}
            padding: [0, 0, 0, 0]
               

'''
```

I tried to set the default padding of 8dp to 0dp which helped a little bit, but the result still isn't satisfying.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, there is no way to add a button in between the MDTopAppBar. I tried the same to create a search button on the center but did not work. The only way is to create a custom widget with MDBoxLayout with buttons and heading.

```
Topbar@MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    MDIconButton:
        icon:'menu'
        on_release:root.open()
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
            icon:'magnify'
            text:'search'
        MDLabel:
            text:"MainScreen"
    MDIconButton:
        icon:'home'
```